# Wordpress: Add a logo at different position on each page

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I want to put a logo in the header of a website. I use the theme "Snowbird". In the header.php I want to specify to Wordpress to place the logo a different place on the header, according to each page of the website.

This is the code I add to my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html class="ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemscope="itemscope">

<div class="xf__site hfeed">
   <div class="content-area">
      <div class="logo">
         <a href="#"><img src="https://website/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logo-website.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
      </div>
```

How can I do that ?

Best regard,
Lordaker

Comment: Set the style in the relevant div tag using `style="your properties here"` would be how I would do this. Looks like you'll need to do this on that `<div class="logo">`

Comment: Yes I known I can change the propertie's style of my logo by css. But I want place the logo at different place of my header when by example; If I'm on the home page my logo is center according to the header of page. For the others pages my logo is placed at the top right of my header.

Comment: Wordpress generates `page-id` classes and adds them to the body tag for every page. You can use those to specify changes to `.logo` for example `.page-id-12242 .logo {...}` Wordpress also generates classes for every page type. For example Archive pages have the class `.blog`. Single post pages have the class `.single` The home page has the class `.home` What changes do you want to implement?

Comment: Change the position of logo on each page (Home, About, Technique and Contact). I want my logo center in the header of home page. and for the others top right. With the position absolute, I can do It with css. I don't known pages had some classes genreate by wordpress. Is it the same each time ?

Comment: Yes, once you publish a page or post it gets an a page or post id. The id never changes for that page or post unless you delete it. The home page always has the class `.home` Open the dev tools and look at the classes for the `<body>` tag for the pages you want to modify and use those to target your CSS changes.

Comment: ok, I understand. Thank a lot. (^_^)

Comment: @lordaker There are a lot of cases where the IDs can change. When you have a local version of the site running the IDs are typically different from your production version. It's not a scalable practice to use page IDs as CSS selectors. A best practice, in this case, is to either programmatically add body classes to specific pages or to add a custom field which will allow you choose the position of the logo from the page admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the body_class filter to add classes to the body element of specific pages and then use CSS to do the positioning.

PHP - functions.php

```
function wp_body_classes( $classes ) {
  if ( is_page( 'Demo Page' ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'demo-page';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wp_body_classes' );
```

CSS

```
.demo-page .logo {
   // position
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot, Dedering.